# Is it possible to read bot Telegram messages

Tags: api, logging, bots, telegram, sendmessage

I have successfully created a bot with and am able to fetch messages from a chat using the [**`getupdates`**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method (long polling).

The getUpdates method is only showing user posted messages (clientside). When I post messages directly using the [**`sendmessage`**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method (serverside) these messages do appear in the chat, but do not in the getUpdates log.

This page https://github.com/LibreLabUCM/teleg-api-bot/wiki/Getting-started-with-the-Telegram-Bot-API#getupdates
states it logs only when "An user messages your bot, either directly or in a group." and some other ways, but the sendMessage way is not mentioned.

I've read a bit on the [**`setwebhook`**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) method (push) but am not sure this will fix my issue.

Is this possible?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Are you trying to read all messages in a group or channel? Or are you trying to only read messages posted by a specific bot to a channel? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Reading messages posted my bot through sendMessage is what I am after. Reading all messages would be even better. I have written a script that post messages via cURL to the chat. I'd like to get these bot messages from the chat. Example, the doorbell rings, a photo will be taken and sent to the chat, with an informative text message like the date and more. I'd like to read these messages once after they appeared in the chat.

Comment: Is using telegram API an option (not the bot API)? With telegram API you can easily get all messages.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it!

Comment: Please note telegram API itself is complicated and not well documented. There are however very good clients written in different languages, which in just a short time you can get it going. For example for python there is Telethon and for C# TLSharp.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Bot FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots), bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.

Comment: I am not sure this explains the issue. This is what I am trying to accomplish; Michael (me) is chatting with @ PhotoBot (not real). When Michael adds a message to the chat it appears in getUpdates. When I use @ PhotoBot to add a message, using the sendMessage method, it doesn't. Do you think this is the issue you are refering to? In your link they speak about OTHER bots, in my case it is the SAME bot. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3):

The [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method shows only updates from users, not from the bot itself. This means that when you fetch the new messages with the getUpdates method, the Telegram API will list only the messages sent by the users, not the messages sent by the bot via any method (e.g [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), [`sendPhoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) ...).

To get old messages you can store the entire update (or only the parts of the update you need) for each message (even those sent by the bot with the sendMessage method) in a file or in a database and when you need an old message you can simply fetch it form the database or the files.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get the bot messages using two bots.
One does the **`sendMessage`** method and the other one does the **`getUpdates`** method.

[@Giolacca9 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610258/is-it-possible-to-read-bot-telegram-messages/62543346#62543346) inspired me to try this workaround and it works, *"not from the bot itself"* :)

Comment: This works even though Sean's answer seems right and the docs say otherwise.