# Get last message from Telegram Chat (API)

Tags: api, rest, telegram

How to get the latest message from telegram GET request?
The link doesn't work (404 Not Found).

```
https://api.telegram.org/botХХХ:ХХХ/getChatHistory?chat_id=-XXXXXX
```

Comment: Anyone looking to read **bot** messages check: [Is it possible to read bot Telegram messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73751645/1287812)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to read bot Telegram messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610258/is-it-possible-to-read-bot-telegram-messages)

Comment: @Vega This question has an accepted answer and the linked duplicate question doesn't have an accepted answer, so maybe it would be better to keep both questions open.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73270188/8583692).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution. It's work:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botХХХХ:ХХХХХХ/getUpdates?offset=-1
```

Comment: I got `{"ok":true,"result":[]}` what does it mean? Shouldn't the chat_id be included in the url?